# WP_Query using 's' and tax_query doesn't work (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to make a query in Wordpress using the search box BUT I need that one category doesn't appear in the results. So I have this code:

```
$query_string = array(
        's' => $_GET["s"],
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => array(
                                    'bajo-pedido'
                            ),
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                    ),
            ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
```

However, when I go to my page I see the list of products including those have been marked with "bajo-pedido" category. I find a lot information about this in Google, but all the solutions that I find doesn't really work (including the class wrote by Kevin Leary). Can anybody help me to find the solution of the combining "s" => value with tax_query? (or if exist any other way to make search query with tax_query)

Thanks a lot